# Request-URI Too Large

Tags: php, get, request, capacity

Got this error on a big `$_GET` query in size ~9 000 symbols (they are divided into ~10 variables).

```
Request-URI Too Large

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
```

What is a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Why do you have a URL that is this long?

Comment: Try lowering your URI size. I've never exceeded 200 characters, and that was way to big on itself. You don't need **OVER 9000!!!!** characters....

Comment: "What is a workaround for this problem?" Shorten the URL

Comment: If you need to pass that much data from the client to the server, the workaround would be to place it in a form post instead of in the query string.  Or perhaps in the request body (less commonly used).

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error)

Comment: @brandon I can't change this option on shared hosting

Comment: some different solution, except $_POST?

Comment: No other solution than `POST`. It's why `POST` exists.

Comment: The work around is to shorten your url. 9k in an url is simply insane.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no workaround if you want pass all these info with GET without change server configuration.

Other solutions:

- Use POST with a form (or an hidden form and add onclick event at your link that submit it)
- Use Session. When the server generates the link, store it in $_SESSION with an unique id (or RID, it can be md5 of complete URI) and pass it via GET.
- Use Database or file storage (with the same procedure of session)

Comment: See as well: [How to compress/decompress a long query string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996049/how-to-compress-decompress-a-long-query-string-in-php)

Comment: I think that in this way you just move the problem in the future, when the url will be too large with compression as well. It's better to change logic if you need to pass too much info via get. (My 2 cents)

Comment: That is a related question only, if you read the accepted answer there, you can even see that this is *not* so much in the future but already in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (it needs formData support):

```
<script>
  //Load form
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("param_name1", "param_content1");
  formData.append("param_name2", "param_content2"); 
  formData.append("param_nameN", "param_contentN"); 

  //Send form via AJAX
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", YOUR_URL);  
  xhr.send(formData);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well an URI actually have a character limit depending on several things. You can check it out at

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Compatibility_issues

One workaround is to use POST instead of GET if you are the one developing the server too.