# What are alternatives to use when getting a "network error - uri too large" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, uri

I have a product search which I'm posting to an add-to-basket webservice.

Problem is, I'm visualizing all product variations (say color and size). I just ran into one item in the database, which was available in 10 sizes and 30 colors, resulting in an `network error, uri too large`, because my AJAX was posting this:

```
"NetworkError: 414 Request-URI Too Large - http://www.page.de/test/services/form_cfc?form_submitted=add&s_artikelnummer=TSHIRT+2011+nos+ja&ean1=2011301051003&menge1=&ean2=2011301051004&menge2=&ean3=2011301051005&menge3=&ean4=2011301051006&menge4=&ean5=2011301051007&menge5=&ean6=2011301051008&menge6=&ean7=2011301051009&menge7=&ean8=2011301051010&menge8=&ean9=2011301051011&menge9=&ean10=2011301050903&menge10=&ean11=2011301050904&menge11=&ean12=2011301050905&menge12=&ean13=2011301050906&menge13=&ean14=2011301050907&menge14=&ean15=2011301050908&menge15=&ean16=2011301050909&menge16=&ean17=2011301050910&menge17=&ean18=2011301050911&menge18=&ean19=2011301050803&menge19=&ean20=2011301050804&menge20=&ean21=2011301050805&menge21=&ean22=2011301050806&menge22=&ean23=2011301050807&menge23=&ean24=2011301050808&menge24=&ean25=2011301050809&menge25=&ean26=2011301050810&menge26=&ean27=2011301050811&menge27=&ean28=2011301052103&menge28=&ean29=2011301052104&menge29=&ean30=2011301052105&menge30=&ean31=2011301052106&menge31=&ean32=2011301052107&menge32=&ean33=2011301052108&menge33=&ean34=2011301052109&menge34=&ean35=2011301052110&menge35=&ean36=2011301052111&menge36=&ean37=2011301052003&menge37=&ean38=2011301052004&menge38=&ean39=2011301052005&menge39=&ean40=2011301052006&menge40=&ean41=2011301052007&menge41=&ean42=2011301052008&menge42=&ean43=2011301052009&menge43=&ean44=2011301052010&menge44=&ean45=2011301052011&menge45=&ean46=2011301052203&menge46=&ean47=2011301052204&menge47=&ean48=2011301052205&menge48=&ean49=2011301052206&menge49=&ean50=2011301052207&menge50=&ean51=2011301052208&menge51=&ean52=2011301052209&menge52=&ean53=2011301052210&menge53=&ean54=2011301052211&menge54=&ean55=2011301052303&menge55=&ean56=2011301052304&menge56=&ean57=2011301052305&menge57=&ean58=2011301052306&menge58=&ean59=2011301052307&menge59=&ean60=2011301052308&menge60=&ean61=2011301052309&menge61=&ean62=2011301052310&menge62=&ean63=2011301052311&menge63=&ean64=2011301052903&menge64=&ean65=2011301052904&menge65=&ean66=2011301052905&menge66=&ean67=2011301052906&menge67=&ean68=2011301052907&menge68=&ean69=2011301052908&menge69=&ean70=2011301052909&menge70=&ean71=2011301052910&menge71=&ean72=2011301052911&menge72=&ean73=2011301052703&menge73=&ean74=2011301052704&menge74=&ean75=2011301052705&menge75=&ean76=2011301052706&menge76=&ean77=2011301052707&menge77=&ean78=2011301052708&menge78=&ean79=2011301052709&menge79=&ean80=2011301052710&menge80=&ean81=2011301052711&menge81=&ean82=2011301052603&menge82=&ean83=2011301052604&menge83=&ean84=2011301052605&menge84=&ean85=2011301052606&menge85=&ean86=2011301052607&menge86=&ean87=2011301052608&menge87=&ean88=2011301052609&menge88=&ean89=2011301052610&menge89=&ean90=2011301052611&menge90=&ean91=2011301052803&menge91=&ean92=2011301052804&menge92=&ean93=2011301052805&menge93=&ean94=2011301052806&menge94=&ean95=2011301052807&menge95=&ean96=2011301052808&menge96=&ean97=2011301052809&menge97=&ean98=2011301052810&menge98=&ean99=2011301052811&menge99=&ean100=2011301053003&menge100=&ean101=2011301053004&menge101=&ean102=2011301053005&menge102=&ean103=2011301053006&menge103=&ean104=2011301053007&menge104=&ean105=2011301053008&menge105=&ean106=2011301053009&menge106=&ean107=2011301053010&menge107=&ean108=2011301053011&menge108=&ean109=2011301051903&menge109=&ean110=2011301051904&menge110=&ean111=2011301051905&menge111=&ean112=2011301051906&menge112=&ean113=2011301051907&menge113=&ean114=2011301051908&menge114=&ean115=2011301051909&menge115=&ean116=2011301051910&menge116=&ean117=2011301051911&menge117=&ean118=2011301051803&menge118=&ean119=2011301051804&menge119=&ean120=2011301051805&menge120=&ean121=2011301051806&menge121=&ean122=2011301051807&menge122=&ean123=2011301051808&menge123=&ean124=2011301051809&menge124=&ean125=2011301051810&menge125=&ean126=2011301051811&menge126=&ean127=2011301051403&menge127=&ean128=2011301051404&menge128=&ean129=2011301051405&menge129=&ean130=2011301051406&menge130=&ean131=2011301051407&menge131=&ean132=2011301051408&menge132=&ean133=2011301051409&menge133=&ean134=2011301051410&menge134=&ean135=2011301051411&menge135=&ean136=2011301051703&menge136=&ean137=2011301051704&menge137=&ean138=2011301051705&menge138=&ean139=2011301051706&menge139=&ean140=2011301051707&menge140=&ean141=2011301051708&menge141=&ean142=2011301051709&menge142=&ean143=2011301051710&menge143=&ean144=2011301051711&menge144=&ean145=2011301051503&menge145=&ean146=2011301051504&menge146=&ean147=2011301051505&menge147=&ean148=2011301051506&menge148=&ean149=2011301051507&menge149=&ean150=2011301051508&menge150=&ean151=2011301051509&menge151=&ean152=2011301051510&menge152=&ean153=2011301051511&menge153=&ean154=2011301051603&menge154=&ean155=2011301051604&menge155=&ean156=2011301051605&menge156=&ean157=2011301051606&menge157=&ean158=2011301051607&menge158=&ean159=2011301051608&menge159=&ean160=2011301051609&menge160=&ean161=2011301051610&menge161=&ean162=2011301051611&menge162=&ean163=2011301050203&menge163=&ean164=2011301050204&menge164=&ean165=2011301050205&menge165=&ean166=2011301050206&menge166=&ean167=2011301050207&menge167=&ean168=2011301050208&menge168=&ean169=2011301050209&menge169=&ean170=2011301050210&menge170=&ean171=2011301050211&menge171=&ean172=2011301050103&menge172=&ean173=2011301050104&menge173=&ean174=2011301050105&menge174=&ean175=2011301050106&menge175=&ean176=2011301050107&menge176=&ean177=2011301050108&menge177=&ean178=2011301050109&menge178=&ean179=2011301050110&menge179=&ean180=2011301050111&menge180=&ean181=2011301050603&menge181=&ean182=2011301050604&menge182=&ean183=2011301050605&menge183=&ean184=2011301050606&menge184=&ean185=2011301050607&menge185=&ean186=2011301050608&menge186=&ean187=2011301050609&menge187=&ean188=2011301050610&menge188=&ean189=2011301050611&menge189=&ean190=2011301050703&menge190=&ean191=2011301050704&menge191=&ean192=2011301050705&menge192=&ean193=2011301050706&menge193=&ean194=2011301050707&menge194=&ean195=2011301050708&menge195=&ean196=2011301050709&menge196=&ean197=2011301050710&menge197=&ean198=2011301050711&menge198=&ean199=2011301050303&menge199=&ean200=2011301050304&menge200=&ean201=2011301050305&menge201=&ean202=2011301050306&menge202=&ean203=2011301050307&menge203=&ean204=2011301050308&menge204=&ean205=2011301050309&menge205=&ean206=2011301050310&menge206=&ean207=2011301050311&menge207=&ean208=2011301050503&menge208=&ean209=2011301050504&menge209=&ean210=2011301050505&menge210=&ean211=2011301050506&menge211=&ean212=2011301050507&menge212=&ean213=2011301050508&menge213=&ean214=2011301050509&menge214=&ean215=2011301050510&menge215=&ean216=2011301050511&menge216=&ean217=2011301050403&menge217=&ean218=2011301050404&menge218=&ean219=2011301050405&menge219=&ean220=2011301050406&menge220=&ean221=2011301050407&menge221=&ean222=2011301050408&menge222=&ean223=2011301050409&menge223=&ean224=2011301050410&menge224=&ean225=2011301050411&menge225=&ean226=2011301052403&menge226=&ean227=2011301052404&menge227=&ean228=2011301052405&menge228=&ean229=2011301052406&menge229=&ean230=2011301052407&menge230=&ean231=2011301052408&menge231=&ean232=2011301052409&menge232=&ean233=2011301052410&menge233=&ean234=2011301052411&menge234=&ean235=2011301052503&menge235=&ean236=2011301052504&menge236=1&ean237=2011301052505&menge237=1&ean238=2011301052506&menge238=1&ean239=2011301052507&menge239=&ean240=2011301052508&menge240=&ean241=2011301052509&menge241=&ean242=2011301052510&menge242=&ean243=2011301052511&menge243=&ean244=2011301051203&menge244=&ean245=2011301051204&menge245=1&ean246=2011301051205&menge246=1&ean247=2011301051206&menge247=1&ean248=2011301051207&menge248=&ean249=2011301051208&menge249=&ean250=2011301051209&menge250=&ean251=2011301051210&menge251=&ean252=2011301051211&menge252=&ean253=2011301051103&menge253=&ean254=2011301051104&menge254=&ean255=2011301051105&menge255=&ean256=2011301051106&menge256=1&ean257=2011301051107&menge257=&ean258=2011301051108&menge258=&ean259=2011301051109&menge259=&ean260=2011301051110&menge260=&ean261=2011301051111&menge261=&ean262=2011301051303&menge262=&ean263=2011301051304&menge263=&ean264=2011301051305&menge264=1&ean265=2011301051306&menge265=1&ean266=2011301051307&menge266=&ean267=2011301051308&menge267=&ean268=2011301051309&menge268=&ean269=2011301051310&menge269=&ean270=2011301051311&menge270=&artikel_anzahl=270&radio_add=1&method=process&returnformat=JSON"
```

**Question:**
what to do? I can't change the underlying procedure, so is the only way limiting the amount of variations a user can create? This is an edge case, but nevertheless.

Thanks for input!

Comment: Do you mean that you can't replace GET with POST?

Answer (score 4):

Post the data instead of passing it in the url. It is probably a minor tweak, but you can post a lot more data. The maximum uri length depends on both the client and the server. For IIS the default is 2Kb (about 2000 characters), although it can be modified to be much larger. I think IE used the same limit, although I'm not sure about newer versions.

Anyway, a max of 2Kb is a limit you should respect although it's not an official limit. If the data is larger, post it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this better http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E414.html

This too may help [Request-URI Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877744/request-uri-too-large)

OR

[How do I resolve a HTTP 414 "Request URI too long" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2891574/1723626)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Use POST instead of GET.