# Large querystring compression

Tags: url, xor, compression, querystringparameter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compress/decompress a long query string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996049/how-to-compress-decompress-a-long-query-string-in-php)

I have a huge amount of data inside my subquerystring for tracking needs.

I loose a lot of my data because of this too large url missinterpreted by clients or search engine or brower capability.

To avoid this problematics, I've decided to compress my querystrings into a smaller one.
I've looked into the direction of xor, huffman, lzw & gzdeflate compression algorithm but I'm not satisfied for my url needs (I need to url encode after that...).

*Questions :*

- Do you know any other algorythm which can fullfill my needs ?
- Do you know which compression technics is the most efficient ?

*More details:*

- No Post/Session method possible.
- Every alphanumeric char can be inside the query string.
- I have around 30 parameters to compress

Comment: Why so much in the querystring? If you're passing that much data, you should be using POST

Comment: How large?, can you show an example.

Comment: @Mark Baker : It's affiliate url, so... no post.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone : 
minimum -> 1k,
maximum -> 5k of char

Comment: @Dark - have a look at [Maximum length of a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

Comment: @ghoti : I know, that's why I need to compress my data ;)

Comment: Take a look at this chart of [compression rates for various algorithms](http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/text.php). Even with 80% compression you would still be flirting with the 2000 character limit that @ghoti mentioned. Query strings are not the right method for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @deceze - great post!  How on earth do you remember something like that from so long ago?!  I barely remember answers I wrote a month ago.

Comment: @deceze https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+large+querystring+compression&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=php+Large+querystring+compression&oq=php+Large+querystring+compression&gs_l=serp.3...8592.8592.0.9058.1.1.0.0.0.0.73.73.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.2.B8qMS4hUxgo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=973a42b6a2364274&bpcl=35466521&biw=1235&bih=1052

Comment: @ghoti The truth is, I am an elephant with appropriately awesome memory. I dictate to a small Indian boy who types what I say on a keyboard.

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of data you are sending? i.e. is one long text variable, or lots of smaller vars, arrays, encoded characters... and so on

Comment: All the char on your keyword can be inside it. Around 30 parameters.

Comment: Ok - I don't think you get what I meant... obviously any character can appear in the URL. A way to minimise large urls is to do away with the extra clutter certain constructions can add, like [] brackets or characters that have to be encoded *(each encoded character can add an extra 2+ characters)* -- similar to rison's approach (http://mjtemplate.org/examples/rison.html) - however you aren't encoding another structure inside a url so it's slightly different.

Comment: When you aren't satisfied with xor, huffman etc.pp why don't you use an url shortener?

Comment: It won't change the problem. "I loose a lot of my data because of this too large url missinterpreted by clients or search engine or brower capability.". At the end with shortening system it finished with a 301 & the same crash with the browser.